# Jquery autocomplete clear textbox value if match not found

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, textbox

I've made a autocomplete textbox when i key in the value which are not available in the list it will auto clear the textbox which the result is correct, but when i key in the data which are inside the list and added some wordings to it, the textbox value are not clear although the final key in value are not inside the list.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var source = ['jQuery', 'Dojo', 'ExtJs', 'Prototype', 'Java', 'Android', 'MySQL', 'PHP'];

    $("input#myDropDown").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: source,
        autoFocus: true,
        scroll: true,
    }).focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    }).live("blur", function(event) {
        var autocomplete = $(this).data("autocomplete");
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i");
        autocomplete.widget().children(".ui-menu-item").each(function() 
          {
            var item = $(this).data("item.autocomplete");
            if (matcher.test(item.label || item.value || item)) {
                //There was a match, lets stop checking
                autocomplete.selectedItem = item;
                return;
            }
        });

        if (autocomplete.selectedItem) {
            autocomplete._trigger("select", event, {
                item: autocomplete.selectedItem
            });
        //there was no match, clear the input
        } else {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
    .ui-autocomplete { 
                        position: absolute; 
                        cursor: default; 
                        height: 150px; 
                        overflow-y: scroll; 
                        overflow-x: hidden;
                     }
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

       <input id="myDropDown" type="text" name="myDropDown" />
```

### Problem

list of item
[image]

when i select any from the items and add extra wording to it. The values key are no match with the records, but the textbox values are not clear. I need to focus and onblur again the textbox, the textbox just will detect the match and clear the input. 
[image]

Comment: @DelightedD0D thanks for the edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im no expert but I feel like this is happening because the `autocomplete` widget is stealing focus from the actual `input` when you select one of the options by clicking on it. Basically, the input you see that has focus is actually the overlay created by the widget therefore, the `blur` event is on that overlay not the actual `input` you bind the function to.

Adding `select: function( event, ui ) { $(this).focus() }` in your autocomplete options resolves the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var source = ['jQuery', 'Dojo', 'ExtJs', 'Prototype', 'Java', 'Android', 'MySQL', 'PHP'];

    $("input#myDropDown").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: source,
        autoFocus: true,
        scroll: true,
        select: function( event, ui ) { $(this).focus() }
    }).focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    }).live("blur", function(event) {
        var autocomplete = $(this).data("autocomplete");
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i");
        autocomplete.widget().children(".ui-menu-item").each(function() 
          {
            var item = $(this).data("item.autocomplete");
            if (matcher.test(item.label || item.value || item)) {
                //There was a match, lets stop checking
                autocomplete.selectedItem = item;
                return;
            }
        });

        if (autocomplete.selectedItem) {
            autocomplete._trigger("select", event, {
                item: autocomplete.selectedItem
            });
        //there was no match, clear the input
        } else {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete { 
                        position: absolute; 
                        cursor: default; 
                        height: 150px; 
                        overflow-y: scroll; 
                        overflow-x: hidden;
                     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


       <input id="myDropDown" type="text" name="myDropDown" />
```

Answer (score 0):

how if use mysql as a source how to clear text if not matches with db ?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#kodebrg").change(function(){
   var kodebrg = $("#kodebrg").val();
   $.ajax({
    url: "getperangkatnama.php",
    data: "kodebrg=" + kodebrg,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
     $("#namabrg").html(data.namabrg);
     
     //$("#idbag").html(data.idbag);
    }
   });
  }); 

 });
</script>
```